# OWL Reader::read () error

Tags: php, owl, ontology

Im trying to send my search variable to ontology and see if it does belong to any class or subclass as their property. how can i do that?

```
 <?php 
        $search=$_GET['searchtext'];

        if(empty($search)){
            echo ("You don't enter anything.");
    }
    else{
          echo ("String you enter is " . $search . " !");
    }


        require_once "owllib/OWLLib.php";
        require_once "$OWLLIB_ROOT/reader/OWLReader.php";
        require_once "$OWLLIB_ROOT/memory/OWLMemoryOntology.php";

        $reader = new OWLReader();
        $ontology = new OWLMemoryOntology();
        $reader->read($filename, $ontology);
        $class = $ontology->getClass($search); 

        echo("Ontology output is " .$class);


    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a reasoner available to you?  You could have a class hierarchy, e.g., `House subClassOf Residence` and an assertion `WhiteHouse a House`, but without a reasoner you won't be able to _infer_ that `WhiteHouse a Residence`.

Comment: Yes I have the reasoner which is company.owl i didnt put it on the code but the filename is company.owl the problem might be the getClass function which is the part of owllib that i have downloaded.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  `company.owl` isn't a reasoner;  it's an OWL ontology.  An OWL reasoner is something like Pellet, or HermiT, or FaCT++ that takes an ontology as input and can _infer_ results that might not have been explicitly stated in the ontology.  (E.g., a reasoner can tell you, based on the axioms that `B subClassOf C` and `x is a B`, that `x is a C`.)

Comment: I havent got any reasoner for myself. I saw from a site that owl can be parsed from php file just like shown above, but its not working correctly. I'm looking for a library to parse my ontology.

Comment: What's "not working correctly" about it?  All I see in the question is some code.  Does it run without error, but not give the output you expect?  Does it produce an error?  What's the file that you're trying to load? There's not enough information here yet for you to be able to get any help. Note that: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: I have a ontology lets say Class food, subclass meat subclass fish and when the $class = $ontology->getClass($search);  is called with search value fish i want to get output of FOOD. Thats what im expected to see, but instead of that, i see whole tree for example food,meat,fish with their ids.

Comment: Comments can be deleted at any time;  please add updates to you question _to the question_ by editing the question.  This is especially true of code, which is _very_ hard to read in comments.  And please be specific.  If you've got an ontology, _show_ it to us.  One of the things that people will try doing is _running_ your code.  If you don't give us legal input, we can't do anything with it.